# Need to hide tinymce menubar in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, tinymce-4

I am trying to remove the TinyMCE menubar below

[image: Menu Bar]
from wordpress via the theme functions.php. I dont want to edit the core/script files. Is this possible? Removing button options is straight forward, but stripping this bar is proving difficult.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using tinyMCE 4 you can set the following in the tinymce init:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    tinymce.init({
        menubar: false
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apologies. A colleague installed advanced TinyMCE without me knowing, so i thought this was wordpress default. I have removed it from there. Question can be disregarded.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable menubar by adding following code in enqueue in your theme function.php , selector is option you can use without it as well as said by Milap.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
   tinymce.init({
   selector: "textarea", 
   menubar: false
 });
</script>
```